# Identifying hash encoding

Tags: bash, unix, hash

I am creating a function that will accept an input and determine if the value is a certain type of hash encoding (md5, sha1, sha256, and sha512). I have asked a few classmates and logically it makes sense, but clearly something is wrong.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

function identify-hash() {
  encryptinput=$(echo $1 | grep -E -i '^[a-z0-9=]+${32}')
  if [[ -n $encryptinput ]]; then
    echo "The $1 is a valid md5sum string"
    exit
  else
    encryptinput=$(echo $1 | grep -E -i '^[a-z0-9=]+${40}')
    if [[ -n $encryptinput ]]; then
      echo "The $1 is a valid sha1sum string"
      exit
    else
      encryptinput=$(echo $1 | grep -E -i '^[a-z0-9=]+${64}')
      if [[ -n $encryptinput ]]; then
        echo "The $1 is a valid sha256sum string"
        exit
      else
        encryptinput=$(echo $1 | grep -E -i '^[a-z0-9=]+${128}')
        if [[ -n $encryptinput ]]; then
          echo "The $1 is a valid sha512sum string"
          exit
        else
          echo "Unable to determine the hash function used to generate the input"
        fi
      fi
    fi
  fi
}

identify-hash $1
```

I know that hashes have a specific number of characters for them, but I don't know exactly why it's not working. Removing the **{32}** out of line **4** allows it to answer as a md5sum, but than it assumes everything is md5sum.

Suggestions?

Comment: What do you think putting a repeat count after the end-of-line anchor will do?

Comment: Forgive me Im still new to bash coding. Elaborate that please?

Comment: @Sin950 In regex syntax, a brace expression like `{32}` says there should be that many repetitions of the *immediately preceding item*. So `...${32}` means thirty-two ends-of-lines.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Ok, than that is different to what I was led to believe **{32}** meant than. Removing those than allows it to check, but basically now it says any hash put in is a md5 hash so it's not comparing correctly like before. How would I get the input to compare correctly?

Comment: what you meant to do is `^[a-z0-9=]{n}$` where `n`  is the number of characters in your hash. changing all statements to this syntax should fix it up

Comment: an aside, bash has [builtin regex check](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions-1). here's a simple [cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/bash#conditions) i often refer

Comment: @kevinnls You beautiful person thank you so much for this. I have been beating my head against a brick wall for the last few hours trying to figure this out.

Comment: You should not accept `[g-z=]`. The checksums contain `[a-f0-9]`.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed your script. I advise you would have spotted most of the issues if you had used [ShellCheck](https://shellcheck.net/):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

identify_hash() {
  # local variables
  local -- encrypt_input
  local -- sumname

  # Regex capture the hexadecimal digits
  if [[ "$1" =~ ([[:xdigit:]]+) ]]; then
    encrypt_input="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  else
    encrypt_input=''
  fi

  # Determine name of sum algorithm based on length of encrypt_input
  case "${#encrypt_input}" in
    32) sumname=md5sum ;;
    40) sumname=sha1sum ;;
    64) sumname=sha256sum ;;
    128) sumname=sha512sum ;;
    *) sumname=;;
  esac

  # If sum algorithm name found (sumname is not empty)
  if [ -n "$sumname" ]; then
    printf 'The %s is a valid %s string\n' "$encrypt_input" "$sumname"
  else
    printf 'Unable to determine the hash function used to generate the input\n' >&2
    exit 1
  fi
}

identify_hash "$1"
```

Comment: Using [tag:bash] you could: `local -ar sumnames=([32]=md5sum [40]=sha1sum [64]=sha256sum [128]=sha512sum)`.

Answer (score 1):

Something shorter, using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
checkHash() {
    local -ar sumnames=([32]=md5sum [40]=sha1sum [64]=sha256sum [128]=sha512sum)
    [[ "$1" =~ [[:xdigit:]]{32,129} ]]
    echo "${sumnames[${#BASH_REMATCH}]+String $BASH_REMATCH could be }${sumnames[
                              ${#BASH_REMATCH}]:-No hash tool match this string.}"
}
```

This will *extract* `[:xdigit:]` part out of any complete line:

```
checkHash 'Filename: 13aba32dbe4db7a7117ed40a25c29fa8 --'
String 13aba32dbe4db7a7117ed40a25c29fa8 could be md5sum

checkHash a32dba32dbe4db7a7117ed40a25c29fa8e4db7a7117ed40a25c29fa8
No hash tool match this string.

checkHash a32dba32dbe4db7a7117ed40a25c29fa8e4db7a7117ed40a25c29fa8da921adb 
String a32dba32dbe4db7a7117ed40a25c29fa8e4db7a7117ed40a25c29fa8da921adb could be sha256sum
```

... then `${var+return this only if $var exist}`

... and `${var:-return this if $var is empty}`

Answer (score 0):

Further explaining [@Gordon Davissons' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69369976/identifying-hash-encoding#comment122611753_69369976) and some basics for anyone who stops by

***NB** This answer is extremely simplified to apply only to the current question. here's [my preferred guide](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html) for more regex*

#### Basics of regex

1. `^` - start of a *line*
2. `$` - end of a *line*
3. `[...]` - list of *possible* characters

   - has special sauce
   - `a-z` = all lowercase (English) letters; `0-9` = all digits; etc.
   - also accepts [character *classes*](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html) - e.g [`[:xdigit:]`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html#index-xdigit-character-class) for [hexadecimal characters](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal#:%7E:text=Hexadecimal%20uses%20the%20decimal%20numbers,and%20hexadecimal%20F%20%3D%20decimal%2015.)

     - the expression is now `[[:xdigit:]]` - i.e `[:class:]` inside `[...]`
4. `{...}` - number of times the *preceding* expression should be matched

   - `^[a]{1}$` will match `a` but not `aa`
   - `^f[o]{2}d$` will match `food` but not `fod, foood, fooo*d`
   - `^[a-z]{4}$` will match

     - `ball` ✔️ but not `buffalo` ❌
     - `cove` ✔️ but not `cover` ❌
     - basically any *line* ( because of the `^...$`) containing a **[string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_(computer_science)#:%7E:text=In%20computer%20programming%2C%20a%20string%20is%20traditionally%20a%20sequence%20of%20characters)** of *exactly* 4 (English) alphabetic characters
   - `{1,5}` - at least `1` and at most `5`
   - `*` - shorthand for `{0,}` meaning 0 or any number of times
   - `+` - shorthand for `{1,}` meaning at least 1; but no upper limit
   - `?` - shorthand for `{1}`

---

So `${32}` is looking for 32 "end of line" `\n` in jargon and what you need is `[a-z0-9=]{32}` instead

BUT as also pointed out by [Andrej Podzimek in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69369976/identifying-hash-encoding#comment122612476_69369976) you need to match only hexadecimal `[0-9a-f]` characters which is the same as `[:xdigit:]`. Either can be used.

---

**PS**

##### more Basics

1. `.` (fullstop/period) matches ANY character including spaces and special characters
2. `(...)` is to match *patterns*

`[a-z ]*(chicken).*` 
will match anything from `chicken coop` to `chicken soup` and `please pass that chicken cookbook, Alex?`

- `[.]` means period/fullstop not any character
- note the space after `z`  this is to make *space* (ascii 32  ) a possible character
- and `.` is case-insensituve

---

**PPS** if it's for homework/assignment/schoolwork, please specify so in your question :)

Comment: Thank you for this! I'll do that next time I need help! :)